# Branching Processes and Generating Functions: counting number of offspring

Tags: probability, generating-functions

I am told: in a homogeneous branching process , the generating function for the total number of progeny is

$$\phi_0(z) = z\cdot g_0(\phi_0(z))$$

where $g_0(z)$ is the pgf of the first generation.

My problem: I understand the $g_0(\phi_0(z))$ term, since
$$ E(z^{\sum_{i=1}^N Y_{i}}) = g_0(\phi_0(z))$$ where the $Y_i$ is the number of progeny descendant from the $i^{th}$ individual in the first generation (so $N$ must be distributed according to $g_0$).

My question is where does the extra factor of $z$ come from? Is it simply to ensure $\phi_0(0) = 1$? Is there another way to show this?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $Z_n=\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i$ and $R_n(s) = \mathbb E[s^{Z_n}]$, $n\geqslant 0$. Since $Z_1=1+Y_1$, we have $R_1(s) = sg_0(s)$, and by induction it can be shown that 
$$
R_n(s) = sg_0(R_{n-1}(s)).
$$
It can further be shown that $R_n(s)<R_{n+1}(s)$ for each $0<s<1$ and hence decreases monotonically to a limit which satisfies the original expression for the generating function of the total offspring.